# Large subgroups of Symmetric Group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, extremal-combinatorics

Let $n \geq 5$. It is easy to prove that if $H \leqslant S_n$ has index $\leq n$, then $H$ is $A_n$ or $S_{n-1}$.

So my question: can this be improved to $n^2$?
I mean, if $[S_n:H] \leq n^2$, is it true that $H$ is one among $A_n$, $S_{n-1}$, $A_{n-1}$, $S_{n-2}$, $S_{n-2} \times S_2$?

Comment: That's definitely not true for small values of $n$ (e.g. consider $S_3 \times S_5$ in $S_8$), so a better question would be if what you are asking is true for $n \geq n_0$  for some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Subgroups of $S_n$ of small index are very well understood. In particular, the complete list can definitely be determined (including the small exceptions). See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687845/show-that-there-is-no-subgroup-of-s-n-of-order-n-1-n for a similar question and an idea how to approach this.I'll explain more later when I have some time.

Comment: $A_{n-2}$ is normal of index $4$ in $S_{n-2}\times S_2$. The quotient is the Klein group so there are three intermediate subgroups, which have index $n(n-1)$ in $S_n$. One of them is $S_{n-2}$, but there is also $A_{n-2}\times S_2$ and another one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted by others what you are asking for is not true in general. You also missed two infinite families which lie in between $A_{n-2}$ and $S_{n-2} \times S_2$. One of them is $A_{n-2} \times S_2$, and the other one is a copy of $S_{n-2}$ realized as $\{(\sigma, \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)) : \sigma \in S_{n-2}\}$ in $S_{n-2} \times S_2$.

But besides this there are only finitely many other examples.

See Theorem 5.2B in *Permutation Groups* by Dixon and Mortimer, which states the following:

> Let $S = \operatorname{Sym}(\Omega)$ and $A = \operatorname{Alt}(\Omega)$, where $n = |\Omega| \geq 5$. Suppose that $G \leq S$ has index $[S:G] < \binom{n}{r}$ for some $1 \leq r \leq n/2$. Then one of the following holds:
>
> 1. There exists $\Delta \subseteq \Omega$ with $|\Delta| < r$ such that $A_{(\Delta)} \leq G \leq S_{\{\Delta\}}$.
> 2. $n = 2m$ is even, $G$ is imprimitive with two blocks of size $m$, and $[S:G] = \frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{m}$.
> 3. One of six exceptional cases hold, with $(n,r,[S:G])$ equal to one of following:
>
>    - $(6,3,15)$, $(5,2,6)$, $(6,2,6)$, $(6,2,12)$, $(7,3,30)$, $(8,3,30)$.

(For details about the exceptional cases, see Dixon and Mortimer's book.)

Apply this result with $r = 3$, and you will find that except for a finite number of examples (which can be determined case-by-case), $[S_n:H] \leq n^2$ implies that up to conjugacy in $S_n$, the subgroup $H$ is one of the following: $S_n$, $A_n$, $S_{n-1}$, $A_{n-1}$, $S_{n-2}$, $S_{n-2} \times S_2$, $A_{n-2} \times S_2$, the other copy of $S_{n-2}$ in $S_{n-2} \times S_2$ described above.

With enough patience, I guess you could use the same approach to classify $H < S_n$ with $[S_n : H] \leq n^3$.

Comment: You are missing another infinite family: there are three groups between $A_{n-2}$ and $S_{n-2}\times S_2$. You only have two of them. (The last one is harder to describe, it is actually isomorphic to $S_{n-2}$ but it does not fix any points. It is generated by a canonical copy of $A_{n-2}$ and a "diagonal" double transposition, which moves the two fixed points.)

Comment: @verret: Oh right, thanks. I think the other one we can realize as $\{(\sigma, \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)) : \sigma \in S_{n-2}\}$ in $S_{n-2} \times S_2$. (Interpreting the sign of a permutation as a homomorphism $\operatorname{sgn}: S_{n-2} \rightarrow S_2$)

Comment: (I'm assuming we are doing things up to conjugacy in $S_n$.)

Comment: In general, this gives $8$ conjugacy classes of subgroups. I did a computer check, and these seem to be the only ones starting at $n=9$. (This should follow from the theorem you stated, with a bit of extra work.) There are plenty of exceptions for smaller $n$. For example, for $n=6$, there are $19$ classes in total.

Comment: @verret: Thanks, that seems correct since $\binom{n}{3} \geq n^2$ for $n \geq 9$, and also $\frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{n/2} > n^2$ if $n > 8$. Also, for $n = 8$ we get $11$ conjugacy classes. The extra three are $S_3 \times S_5$ (mentioned in a comment above), $S_4 \wr S_2$ (case 2. of the theorem), and $AGL_3(2)$ (one of the exceptional cases in 3. of the theorem).

Comment: Thanks to both of you. As you pointed out, I was actually looking for large values of $n$, and the question is in the spirit "there are only "trivial" (perhaps "intransitive" is the right word here) subgroups of index $n^2$ ?" Then the answer seems to be yes.

Comment: @Luca Sabatini Yes, for large values of $n$, the largest transitive subgroup of $S_n$ is $S_{n/2} \wr S_2$ (for $n$ even), which has index $\binom{n}{n/2}/2$ (which grows quite quickly with $n$). This is the same group which appears in Arturo's answer (since it provides a counterexample when $n$ is small).

Answer (score 5):

The group $S_{2n}$ has a subgroup $S_n\wr S_2$, induced by partitioning $\{1,\ldots,2n\}$ into two sets of $n$ elements. This is a subgroup of order $2(n!)^2$. When $n=3$, you get a subgroup of order $72$ inside the group of order $6!=720$, that is, index $10\lt 6^2$. This subgroup is the semidirect product to $(S_3\times S_3)\rtimes S_2$, which I think is not on your list.

Comment: What does the notation $S_n\wr S_2$ mean?

Comment: @Eric: The [unrestricted wreath product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product) of $S_n$ by $S_2$.