# transitive subgroups in $S_n$ that are isomorphic to $S_k$ for $k\leq n$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, permutations, symmetric-groups

Assume that there is a transitive subgroup  $H$ of $S_n$ w.r.t. the standard action $S_n\curvearrowright \{1,2,\cdots, n\}:=X$ such that $H\cong S_k$. Is there any sharp estimate on the upper bound of $n$ in terms of $k$ for large $n$, say for all $n\geq 5$?

For example, one can show that $S_n=HK$, where $K$ is the stabilizer subgroup of $S_n$ for any point in $X$ and hence $K\cong S_{n-1}$. Hence we know $n!\leq k!\cdot (n-1)!$, thus, $n\leq k!$. In particular, is this estimate sharp for $n\geq 5$?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the estimate is sharp. It is realized by the regular action of $S_k$ on itself (Cayley's theorem).

Comment: $S_6$ has a famous transitive subgroup isomorphic to $S_5$. More generally, $S_k$ acts transitively on the set of size two subsets $\{i,j\}$, $1\le i <j\le k$. There are $\binom k2=k(k-1)/2$ such subsets, so we get $S_k$ as a transitive subgroup of $S_{k(k-1)/2}$.

Comment: Oops. You were really asking about the upper bound for $n$, given $k$. :-). Luckily runway44 handled that. I think it is more interesting to try and describe *the smallest* $n>k$ that works for a given $k$.

Comment: @runway44 Thanks!

Comment: Yes, for what Jyrki is talking about, the lower bound for $n$ (other than $k$ itself, of course, and assuming $k>5$), we can look to the O'Nan Scott theorem which classified maximal subgroups of $S_k$ (which is relevant because of orbit-stabilizer theorem). I didn't check but I assume that leads to the example Jyrki mentions, and perhaps there's a low-tech proof as well.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Interesting, is the bound you give the smallest $n>k$ that works for a given $k$?

Comment: For $k=5$ it isn't, because $n=6$ works. Other users, runway44 and all the other users with expertise on group theory know more than I do :-)

Comment: For $k>5$, the smallest value of $n$ is indeed $k(k-1)/2$. This follows from Theorem 5.2B in Permutation Groups by Dixon and Mortimer. See Mikko Korhohen's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536888)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a summary of the answers in the comments.

As runway44 says, the answer to the question asked is yes, $k!$ is a sharp upper bound, because the regular representation of $S_k$ is transitive on $n=k!$ points.

A possibly more interesting question would be to as for a lower bound for $n$ in terms of $k$ with $n>k$. This is $k(k-1)/2$ for $k>2$ and $k \ne 5$. For $k=5$ we can have $n=6$.